# How do I position a mesh just outside the camera view?

Tags: unity

I want to slide in an object into view, coming from the right of the screen.

In order to achieve this, I need to position the object next to the camera view, so that it is still not visible, but close enough for a quick slide in.

For example, placing the object at X=1000000 (so that it is surely outside the camera view) for safety wouldn't work as it couldn't slide in quickly enough. For a reasonable slide, I would need to have it really close next to the camera view.

How could I calculate the object's position for that?

Thank you.

Edit:

Here is the script that I'm now using and which I'm still having problems with:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        float fDist = Mathf.Abs(Camera.main.transform.position.z - this.transform.position.z);
        Bounds b = BoundsFromTransform(this.transform);

        this.transform.position = GetPointLeftOfCamera(Camera.main, fDist, b.size.magnitude / 2);
    }

    public static Bounds BoundsFromTransform(Transform uTransform)
    {

        Bounds bounds = new Bounds(uTransform.position, Vector3.zero);

        foreach (Renderer renderer in uTransform.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>())
        {
            bounds.Encapsulate(renderer.bounds);
        }

        Vector3 nOff = bounds.center - uTransform.position;

        return new Bounds(nOff, bounds.size);
    }
    public static Vector3 GetPointLeftOfCamera(Camera camera, float distance, float goDiameter)
    {
        // 1.
        var ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(0, camera.pixelHeight / 2f, 0));

        // 2.
        var borderPoint = ray.GetPoint(distance);

        // 3.
        var leftPlane = GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes(camera)[0];
        var frustumLeft = leftPlane.normal;

        // 4.
        var halfDiameter = goDiameter / 2f;
        return borderPoint + frustumLeft * halfDiameter;
    }
    public static Vector3 GetPointRightOfCamera(Camera camera, float distance, float goDiameter)
    {
        var ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(camera.pixelWidth - 1, camera.pixelHeight / 2f, 0));
        var borderPoint = ray.GetPoint(distance);

        var rightPlane = GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes(camera)[1];
        var frustumRight = rightPlane.normal;

        var halfDiameter = goDiameter / 2f;
        return borderPoint + frustumRight * halfDiameter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that using Camera.ScreenPointToRay() like this:

1. Get the [camera ray](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenPointToRay.html) of the left/right most edge at the desired height.
2. Then from that ray, [take the point](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Ray.GetPoint.html) at the desired distance.
3. Get the [plane normal](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane.html) for the left/right [camera frustum plane](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes.html)
4. From that point, move to the left/right by half the [renderer diameter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-bounds.html).

If you place your object that that end point, it is just out of view, at a desired distance and near the edge of your camera frustum.

**Code example:**

```
public static Vector3 PlaceOutsideFrustum(this Camera camera, Bounds bounds, float distance, bool left)
{
    var frustumPlanes = GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes(camera);
    Ray ray;
    Plane plane;

    if (left)
    {
        // 1.
        ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(0, camera.pixelHeight / 2f, 0));
        plane = frustumPlanes[0];
    }
    else
    {
        ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(camera.pixelWidth - 1, camera.pixelHeight / 2f, 0));
        plane = frustumPlanes[1];
    }

    // 2.
    var borderPoint = ray.GetPoint(distance);

    // 3.
    var frustumOutside = -plane.normal;

    // 4.
    var halfDiameter = bounds.size.magnitude / 2f;
    return borderPoint + frustumOutside * halfDiameter;
}
```

**Usage example:**

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Renderer))]
public class PlaceOutsideCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool left = true;
    public float distance = 20f;
    public Camera camera;

    void OnEnable()
    {
        if (camera == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var myRenderer = this.GetComponent<Renderer>();
        var bounds = myRenderer.bounds;
        this.transform.position = camera.PlaceOutsideFrustum(bounds, distance, left);
    }
}
```

**Note:**
Keep in mind, the goDiameter is the magnitude of the object renderer (mesh diameter in world space).
Also the object won't be directly touching the border of the camera frustum, as I approximated the mesh to a sphere by using the goDiameter.

If you need more precision, you can still use the same approach and replace the diameter offset calculation with your own.

**Note 2:**
The distance is not exact.
Because of the offset along the frustum left/right vector, the distance between the camera and the object is slightly larger than the distance passed to the method.
If that is a problem, one can fix that by normalizing the direction vector and scaling it to the desired length:

```
[...]
var position = camera.PlaceOutsideFrustum(bounds, distance, true);
var direction = (position - camera.transform.position).normalized;
this.transform.position = camera.transform.position + direction * distance;
```

Comment: How would I get the mesh's diameter?

Comment: I'm asking because unfortunately your approach doesn't work for me, and I'm trying to investigate where I may have gone wrong.

Comment: The easiest way would be to use the [renderer.bounds](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-bounds.html). Then just take bounds.size.magnitude / 2 to get the half diameter. I couldn't test my approach above, as I'm not around my workplace atm. So please let me know if that helped or not. Might need to recheck the code.

Comment: I am using Bounds. Could you please write out the magnitude / 2 code as I'm not perfectly sure how that should look? Thank you.

Comment: Actually it shouldnt be divided by two, the method requires the full diameter. bounds.size.magnitude gives you the diameter. You pass this diameter to the method as goDiameter and it should work.

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me what I should use for distance? Is this correct?         float fDist = Mathf.Abs(Camera.main.transform.position.z - this.transform.position.z); I'm asking because there's still an offset: A part of the object is still visible. Not just a few pixel, but around 20% of the object's width.

Comment: ps: This works ALMOST correct for my case: (Bounds.size.x * 2). I'm dealing with a cube. There are just a few pixels visible of the cube. What might be the reason for these few pixels?

Comment: Do you think you could also show how to position the mesh on the right side instead of on the left side? Perhaps it's easy, but I don't see how.

Comment: Ah, that could be, because I used camera.transform.left, instead of the left of the frustum. I'm currently afk, I'll look into it when I'm back.

Comment: Could you please have a look again? I would also very much like to know how to make show it on the right instead of at the left. Thank you very much!!

Comment: I found a small error in my example code and fixed it. Furthermore, I incorporated the frustum left and added an example for the right hand side. I hope this works for you.

Comment: I'm still having problems with the code. Now it places the cube inside the camera's view. I have added my code to the original posting. Do you see anything that I'm doing wrong in my call to your method?

Comment: Hmmm, seems that the plane normals point to the inside of the frustum. I assumed they would point outward. I fixed it.

Comment: Thank you, but it's still not right. Now the cube is even more "centered". I have also noticed that the code changes the cube's distance to the camera. Do you see any flaw in my distance calculation?

Comment: This evening Ill have access to a development environment again, then I'll test it out. Until now it was only theoretically working code. I'll update as soon as I have something functional.

Comment: So, I adapted the code and made it simpler to use. However, the way it works is still the same. On my pc it works. As for your code, you calculated the distance between the target and "this.transform", but later used Camera.main. Is the component attached to the camera?

Comment: Thank you. I guess I see now what the culprit is. I call your method on each Update, and you only do it once in OnEnable. Is it not allowed / ok to call it on each Update? I mean it's not economic, but I wanted to do it this way in order to test it comfortable while resizing my game window.

Comment: If you call it in update, it will just place the object continuously instead of once. The position shoulnd't be affected.

Comment: For me, it does affect the results. Could you have a look?

Comment: And please don't use a fixed distance! Can you use my approach? ->         float fDist = Mathf.Abs(Camera.main.transform.position.z - this.transform.position.z); I have the script on the Cube, so it should be fine.

Comment: I'm not going to provide all your code. I provide a solution to the original question: "How to calculate the objects position". The solution is flexible enough to allow for any distance. I only used a fixed distance in the usage example. 
If you want to continue this chat, I would suggest we move it to a chat room.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97769/discussion-between-tmighty-and-chillersanim).

Answer (score 0):

You would need to place the object just outside the camera's [view frustum](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnderstandingFrustum.html).

There are many ways to get frustum info. You can see [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.CalculateFrustumCorners.html) for one method with the Unity API.

Comment: I have tried that, and the object was far away from where I thought it would be. Could you perhaps be some more distinctive in your answer?

Comment: Can you show what you tried?

Comment: Vector3[] frustumCorners = new Vector3[4];
        Camera.main.CalculateFrustumCorners(new Rect(0, 0, 1, 1), Camera.main.farClipPlane, Camera.MonoOrStereoscopicEye.Mono, frustumCorners);
        Vector2 worldSpaceCorner = Camera.main.transform.TransformVector(frustumCorners[0]);
        TheExtraTable.transform.position = worldSpaceCorner; I expected the worldspacecorner to be around X = 2, but it's -1000.

Comment: It could be because you are using the far clip plane distance (Camera.main.farClipPlane) as depth. If you try Camera.main.nearClipPlane is that closer to what you expect? This depth should be near the camera's position.

Comment: Yes, nearClipPlane is much closer with X being 0.3f, but still not what I would consider "expected".

Comment: Why do you expect X = 2?

Comment: I have manually placed the object just outside the camera view, and the position's X value was ~2.

Comment: Using the mentioned code, I don't see how the distance between the object and the camera comes into play. I guess this distance influences the required value as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an "ObjectSpawner" game object as a child of your camera and place it slightly outside of the field of view of the camera. When the camera moves or rotates, so will your object spawner.

The object spawner would be pretty standard: Instantiate a prefab at its own world position and with its own world rotation.